# context.getcachedir() returns null pointer exception

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I developed an application but i got the error listed below

```
package rankingfraud.others;

import java.io.File;
import android.content.Context;

public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context) {
    // Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(
                android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "ParseGridView");
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url) {
    String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    // String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear() {
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
    if (files == null)
        return;
    for (File f : files)
        f.delete();
}

}
```

I got the error in logcat as

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(1236): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1236): Process:pack.rankingfraud, PID: 1236

E/AndroidRuntime(1236): java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(1236): at rankingfraud.others.FileCache.<init>    (FileCache.java:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(1236): at rankingfraud.others.ImageLoader.<init>(ImageLoader.java:35)

E/AndroidRuntime(1236): at pack.rankingfraud.SingleAppInfo$GetApp.onPostExecute     

  (SingleAppInfo.java:208)

E/AndroidRuntime(1236): at pack.rankingfraud.SingleAppInfo$GetApp.onPostExecute     

  (SingleAppInfo.java:1)

  E/AndroidRuntime(1236): at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
  E/AndroidRuntime(1236): at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    E/AndroidRuntime(1236):at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage

 (AsyncTask.java:645)

E/AndroidRuntime(1236):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(1236):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(1236):at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5017)

E/AndroidRuntime(1236):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(1236): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(1236):at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

(ZygoteInit.java:779)

E/AndroidRuntime(1236): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

 E/AndroidRuntime(1236): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Above coding return Null Pointer Exception i.e Context is Null.

Comment: you answered it already: `context is null`.

Comment: Yes But i dont know how to solve

Comment: check where the `context` parameter comes from when calling the method, using [@NonNull](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/NonNull.html) annotation may also help

Comment: How to use NonNull notation

Comment: @Naga, where are you calling the method. Please add the code of you calling the method and passing in the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Naga,

Here is where the problem lies. `cacheDir` is a class. When you instantiate it with the constructor `cacheDir(Context context)` , you need to pass in the application context from wherever you are passing it in from. As long as the context is not null, you will be able to use the method without a Null Pointer Exception. 
If you can trace back you where you do the method call, the problem can be resolved there. If you edit the question to reflect that, we should be able to pin point it.